# Why are these corrected sum of squares expressions equivalent?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

How are $$Sxx=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i−\bar x)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i−n\bar x^2$$ where $\bar x=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i/n$ equivalent?

Any help would be much appreciated,

Comment: Not sure why editing is weird, the i = 1 is meant to be under the summation operator. And x-Bar is not aligned properly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incomprehensible.  See the MathJax help at https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help for how to make your formulas readable.

Comment: There is nothing noble here. Just expand the square. See what happens.

Comment: how do you expand brackets of a series?, tried it for a simple case (1,2,3) but cant see algebraically why it works.

Comment: First multiply out the brackets using the binomial formula. Then apply the sum to each term separately.